# Javascript apply check property to checkbox which is inner HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to check checkbox  like `$('#riderCheck').attr('checked','true')` on some condition. but the problem is the checbox is in innerHTML. so i am not able to apply check property to checkbox. innerHTML is like

```
innerHtml += '<input type = "checkbox" id="riderCheck" value="Rider"/>'.
```

Hope you guys would able to understand what i want to do.

Thanks

Comment: which some conditions? Could you shows your attempts on a fiddle?

Comment: sorry but i have just started working on javascript and jquery. what is fiddle??

Comment: jsfiddle.net - you could reproduce here a short, self-contained example of what you're trying to do so other user can see what's wrong exactly

Comment: Thanks Calderan for kind information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joseph the dreamer's answer clarifies your issue.

Here is another way you can do it with Javascript, but not sure its applicable to your situation.

```
innerHtml += var html = '<input type = "checkbox" ' + ((condition)?'checked="checked"':'') + ' id="riderCheck" value="Rider"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [wrap the HTML in jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/53Q5Q/1/) to use jQuery methods

```
//Wrap HTML in jQuery. This creates HTML from the string and let's you use jQuery
//methods on it
var html = $('<input type="checkbox" id="riderCheck" value="Rider"/>');

//check it
html.attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: +1 I had exactly the same answer; the 'true' doesn't have to be quoted btw ;-)

Comment: hey joseph ...... still checkbox is not checked with the solution provided by you.

Comment: @ankit updated. I forgot that jQuery refers to the top element when stored in a variable.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer , your `true` is `'true'`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses the `.prop` method for setting properties rather than the usual `.attr` method:

```
jQuery('<input type="checkbox" id="riderCheck" value="Rider" />')
    .prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/7uMZh/